# Rake Capistrano - how to pass dynamic parameters to execute a shell command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, rake, capistrano

In my Rake capistrano script, I am creating shell commands that needs to have dynamic arguments. My rake code is as below

```
execute "sed -i '/SPARK_HOME=/c\\export SPARK_HOME=<arg1>' #{release_path}/backend_layer/configs/hdfs/cluster.sh"
```

How can I call this rake and send the argument <arg1>, so that my command is dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your rake task like below

```
desc 'Passing argument on rake task'
task :symlink_shared, [:arg1] => :environment do |t, args|
  execute "sed -i '/SPARK_HOME=/c\\export SPARK_HOME=#{args.arg1}' #{release_path}/backend_layer/configs/hdfs/cluster.sh"
end
```

then, run the cap script with argument like below

```
cap staging postdeploy:symlink_shared[<your_arg1>]
```